# How to print progress bar with negative values in Python 2.X?

Tags: python, progress-bar, stdout

I am doing some computation between two sensors and I would like to print "graphically" but in the stdout the % of asymetry between the two sensors.

Ex:
I have as a result -20% (meaning that the left sensor is 20% higher than the right one).

I would like to print this, dynamically, on the same line :

If I have -20%:
[___________________-20%########||_____________________________]

If I have 0%:
[_______________________________||_____________________________]

If I have 10%:
[_______________________________||###10%_______________________]

How could I proceed?
I tried with Progressbar API, but it does not allow to do this (only progressive bars, starting from the left).

I would prefer to not use a GUI because I run this in ssh without X11 forwarding.
But if someone have a similar solution with GUI I am also interested in.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Printing a progress bar isn't difficult. The common method is to use the carriage return character (`\r`):

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

import fcntl
import struct
import termios

class ProgressBar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_terminal_width(self):
        try:
            return struct.unpack('hh', fcntl.ioctl(sys.stdout.fileno(), termios.TIOCGWINSZ, '\x00' * 4))[1]
        except IOError:
            return 120

    def display(self, percentage):
        terminal_width = self.get_terminal_width()

        stars = '*' * int((percentage / 100.0) * terminal_width)

        print(stars, end='\r')  # Print out your progress and jump to the beginning of the line
        sys.stdout.flush()      # Flush stdout to make it show up immediately

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    bar = ProgressBar()

    for i in range(100):
        bar.display(i)
        time.sleep(0.03)
```

I'll leave it you to figure out the string manipulations you need to do to get the progress bar showing up in the middle.